# How to write filter in angularjs that separates thousands with free space?

Tags: angularjs

I want to write a filter in angularjs that separates thousands by whitespaces for example

`(1000 -> 1 000)` and if `(1000.555 -> 1 000.555)`.

Now I am trying to do the next but it seems does not work:

```
app.filter('split', function () {
    return function (number, number2) {
        if (number/3==1){
            return number;
        }else{

            return number.split(".")+"."+ number2.split('.')

        }
    }
});
```

and for my input I put the next `<input type="text" {{someExpression|split}} >`

Comment: FYI: after this operation your number isn't a number anymore. You will return an string (just to remind if calculating afterwards with it).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) will help you to solve your problem too. (then maybe duplicate?)

```
app.filter('split', function (x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
});
```

Comment: I have tested it in console, it does not work: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, for x I put 10000

Comment: hmm it works for me. I update my answer. Maybe you have to apapt the filter. Don't copy paste the function just like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
app.filter('split', function () {
    return function (number) {
        number.toLocaleString();
    }
});
```

Comment: and which locales argument would you choose to represent it with whitespaces?